# API authorization flow with Hapijs and oauth 2

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, hapi.js

We are using hapijs and oauth server for authentication. we need to implement role based authorization in hapijs. is below way is fine for hapijs.

1. Register authentication scheme

   ```
   server.auth.scheme('custom', function (server, options) {

        return {

           authenticate: function (request, reply) {
           // calling oauth flow for roles match
        }   
   });
   ```
2. Register authentication strategy & adding auth,roles in server.route

   ```
   server.auth.strategy('default', 'custom');

   server.route({
       method: 'GET',
       path: API_Path,
       config: {
          roles: ['ADMIN', 'USER'],
          auth : 'default'
       },
       handler: function (request, reply) {                
          return reply.act({
              role: 'admin',
              cmd: 'getInfo',
              id: request.params.id
          });
      }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You should register a strategy and validate the credentials like this.

```
const validate = function (request, username, password, callback) {
const user = users[username];
if (!user) {
    return callback(null, false);
}

Bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isValid) => {
    callback(err, isValid, { id: user.id, name: user.name });
});
};

server.auth.strategy(strategy_name, scheme_name, { validateFunc: validate });
```

Your auth should have options like mode, scope, strategy etc

```
...
...
auth :{
    mode:'required',
    strategy:'strategy_name',
    scope: ['ADMIN', 'USER']
},
... 
...
```

You can use [Bell](https://github.com/hapijs/bell)